# Drawing ramified coverings with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw a diagram similar to this one:

[image]

For that I started with the following code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) node {$Y$};
\draw (0,2) node {$X$};
\draw[<-] (0,0.35) -- (0,1.65) node[left, midway] {$f$};
\draw[thick] (1,0) -- (7,0);
\draw[thick] (1,2) -- (7,2);
\draw[thick] (1,2.5) -- (7,2.5);
\draw[thick] (1,1.5) -- (7,1.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The only thing that I don't know how to do is the curvy parts. I would appreciate some indication.

Comment: Although it doesn't have `curvy` links, [`tikz-timing`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-timing) could be useful to draw this kind of diagrams.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This uses the same [`in and out` trick as Skillmon](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/481133/121799) and puts it into a style `dip`, which takes as arguments the horizontal position and the depth, where the sign decides whether the dip is a dip (minus) or a bump (plus). (Let me also mention that you do not need to do something like `\draw[<-] (0,0.35) -- (0,1.65) node[left, midway] {$f$};`. If you name the nodes, you can just do `\draw[<-] (Y) -- (X) node[left, midway] {$f$};` and Ti*k*Z will make sure to shorten the arrow without you having to compute the coordinates.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\newcounter{dip}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[dip/.style args={#1/#2}{/utils/exec=\stepcounter{dip},
insert path={%
coordinate (aux1) ({#1-abs(#2)},0) coordinate (aux2) ({#1+abs(#2)},0) coordinate (aux3)
(aux1) -- (aux2|-aux1) to[out=0,in=180]  
++({abs(#2)},#2) coordinate(dip-\the\value{dip}) to[out=0,in=180]  (aux3|-aux1)
}}]
\begin{scope}[thick,local bounding box=dips]
 \draw (1,2.5) [dip=5.5cm/-2.5mm]-- (7,2.5);
 \fill (dip-1) circle[radius=2pt] node[right=3pt]{$b=1$};
 \draw (1,2) [dip/.list={2.5cm/-2.5mm,5.5cm/2.5mm}] -- (7,2);
 \fill (dip-2) circle[radius=2pt] node[right=3pt]{$b=1$};
 \draw (1,1.5) [dip/.list={2.5cm/2.5mm,5.5cm/-5mm}]  -- (7,1.5);
 \fill (dip-5) circle[radius=2pt] node[above right=0pt and 5pt]{$b=2$};
 \draw (1,1) -- (7,1);
 \draw (1,0.5) [dip=5.5cm/5mm]  -- (7,0.5);
\end{scope}
\node[left=2pt of dips.west] (X) {$X$};
\draw (7,-0.5) -- (1,-0.5)  node[left=2pt] (Y) {$Y$};
\draw[<-] (Y) -- (X) node[left, midway] {$f$};
\foreach \X in {1,2}
 {
  \fill (dip-\X|-Y) circle[radius=2pt];
  \draw[dashed] (dip-\X|-Y) -- (dip-\X|-0,2.75);
 }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Just for fun: a variation for Skillmon.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\newcounter{dip}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[dip/.style={/utils/exec=\stepcounter{dip},
insert path={%
 to[out=0,in=180]  
++(0.25,#1) node[bullet](dip-\the\value{dip}){}
 to[out=0,in=180] ++(0.25,-1*#1)
}},bullet/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt}]
\begin{scope}[thick,local bounding box=dips]
 \draw (1,2.5) -- (5.25,2.5) [dip=-2.5mm]-- (7,2.5);
 \node[right=3pt of dip-1]{$b=1$};
 \draw (1,2)  -- (2.25,2) [dip=-2.5mm] -- (5.25,2) [dip=2.5mm] --(7,2);
 \node[right=3pt of dip-2]{$b=1$};
 \draw (1,1.5) -- (2.25,1.5) [dip=2.5mm] --(5.25,1.5) [dip=-5mm]  -- (7,1.5);
 \node[above right=-1.5pt and 5pt of dip-5]{$b=2$};
 \draw (1,1) -- (7,1);
 \draw (1,0.5) --(5.25,0.5) [dip=5mm] -- (7,0.5);
\end{scope}
\node[left=2pt of dips.west] (X) {$X$};
\draw (7,-0.5) -- (1,-0.5)  node[left=2pt] (Y) {$Y$};
\draw[<-] (Y) -- (X) node[left, midway] {$f$};
\foreach \X in {1,2}
 {
  \draw[dashed] (dip-\X|-Y) node[bullet]{} -- (dip-\X|-0,2.75);
 }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice automation. Just out of curiosity (coding Ti*k*Z is still something I'm not good at), is it possible to also draw the filled circles inside the `dip` style?

Comment: @Skillmon Yes, of course. E.g. `dip/.style args={#1/#2}{/utils/exec=\stepcounter{dip},
insert path={%
coordinate (aux1) ({#1-abs(#2)},0) coordinate (aux2) ({#1+abs(#2)},0) coordinate (aux3)
(aux1) -- (aux2|-aux1) to[out=0,in=180]  
++({abs(#2)},#2) node[circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt](dip-\the\value{dip}){} to[out=0,in=180]  (aux3|-aux1)
}}`.

Answer (score 12):

The following is a pretty manual way to do this. I only did it for the first two lines, I hope you can apply it to the other occurrences. It uses the `in` and `out` keys of the `to` path construction:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) node {$Y$};
\draw (0,2) node {$X$};
\draw[<-] (0,0.35) -- (0,1.65) node[left, midway] {$f$};
\draw[thick] (1,2.5) -- (7,2.5) coordinate(a);
\draw[thick] (1,2) -- (7,2) coordinate(b);
\draw[thick] (1,1.5) -- (7,1.5) coordinate(c);
\draw[thick] (1,0) -- (7,0) coordinate(d);
\draw[thick]
  (a) ++(.25,-.25) coordinate(ab) to[out=180,in=0] (a)
  (ab) to[out=180,in=0] (b)
  (ab) to[out=0,in=180] ++(.25,.25)
  (ab) to[out=0,in=180] ++(.25,-.25)
  ;
\filldraw
  (ab) circle(.05)
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

This is a *proof of concept* how to use `parser` library to define the following "language" :

- `=` stay at the same level
- `u` goes half up
- `U` goes one up
- `d` goes half down
- `D` goes one down
- `x` plot a (red) dot
- `.` end

Here is the code.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\usepgfmodule{parser}
% -----------------------------
% macro that add #1 to the current path when used inside \pgfextra
\def\insertpath#1{\tikzset{insert path={#1}}}
% define the parser "sheet path"
\pgfparserdef{sheet path}{initial}{the character =}{\insertpath{ -- ++(1, 0)}}
\pgfparserdef{sheet path}{initial}{the letter u}{\insertpath{ to[out=0,in=180] ++(1, .5)}}
\pgfparserdef{sheet path}{initial}{the letter U}{\insertpath{ to[out=0,in=180] ++(1,  1)}}
\pgfparserdef{sheet path}{initial}{the letter d}{\insertpath{ to[out=0,in=180] ++(1,-.5)}}
\pgfparserdef{sheet path}{initial}{the letter D}{\insertpath{ to[out=0,in=180] ++(1, -1)}}
\pgfparserdef{sheet path}{initial}{the letter x}{\insertpath{ node[red,scale=4]{.}}}
\pgfparserdef{sheet path}{initial}{the character .}{\pgfparserswitch{final}}
% the sheet interface macro
\def\sheet#1.{\pgfextra{\pgfparserparse{sheet path}#1.}}
% -----------------------------
\begin{document}
  \tikz\draw[thick]
    (0,-1) \sheet======du=.
    (0,-2) \sheet==du==uxd=.
    (0,-3) \sheet==uxd==DU=.
    (0,-4) \sheet=========.
    (0,-5) \sheet======UxD=.;
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1, I didn't know parser, wow!

Answer (score 8):

I think Bézier curves can do the task. It can make sure that the starting points and the ending points of all curves are placed with a consistent ratio.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\def\innersep{.5em}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=\baselineskip+2*\innersep]
\draw (0,0)--(6.5,0);
\draw (0,1.5)--(6.5,1.5);
\draw (0,1)--(4.75,1) .. controls (4.9,1) and (4.85,1.5) .. (5,1.5) .. controls (5.15,1.5) and (5.1,1) .. (5.25,1)--(6.5,1);
\draw (0,2)--(1.25,2) .. controls (1.4,2) and (1.35,2.25) .. (1.5,2.25) .. controls (1.65,2.25) and (1.6,2) .. (1.75,2)--(4.75,2) .. controls (4.9,2) and (4.85,1.5) .. (5,1.5) .. controls (5.15,1.5) and (5.1,2) .. (5.25,2)--(6.5,2);
\draw (0,2.5)--(1.25,2.5) .. controls (1.4,2.5) and (1.35,2.25) .. (1.5,2.25) .. controls (1.65,2.25) and (1.6,2.5) .. (1.75,2.5)--(4.75,2.5) .. controls (4.9,2.5) and (4.85,2.75) .. (5,2.75) .. controls (5.15,2.75) and (5.1,2.5) .. (5.25,2.5)--(6.5,2.5);
\draw (0,3)--(4.75,3) .. controls (4.9,3) and (4.85,2.75) .. (5,2.75) .. controls (5.15,2.75) and (5.1,3) .. (5.25,3)--(6.5,3);
\fill (1.5,2.25) circle (1.5pt) (5,1.5) circle (1.5pt) (5,2.75) circle (1.5pt) (1.5,0) circle (1.5pt) (5,0) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[dashed] (1.5,0)--(1.5,3.25) (5,0)--(5,3.25);
\draw (1.5,2.25) node[right=1ex] {$b=1$};
\draw (5,1.75) node[right=1ex] {$b=2$};
\draw (5,2.75) node[right=1ex] {$b=1$};
\draw (-0.5,0) node (n) {$N$};
\draw (-0.5,2.25) node (m) {$M$};
\draw[-latex] (m)--(n) node[midway,left] {$f$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This is a *proof of concept* how to use `plot[smooth] coordinates` to do this.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=.5,
      sheet/.style={red,thick,smooth},
      point/.style={insert path={node[scale=4]{.}}}]
    % ---- sheets ----
    \foreach[count=\i] \pts in {
      {(0, 0) (1, 0) (2, 0) (3, 0) (6, 0) (7,-1) (8, 0) (9, 0)},%
      {(0, 0) (1, 0) (2,-1) (3, 0) (6, 0) (7, 1) (8, 0) (9, 0)},%
      {(0, 0) (1, 0) (2, 1) (3, 0) (6, 0) (7,-2) (8, 0) (9, 0)},%
      {(0, 0) (1, 0) (2, 0) (3, 0) (6, 0) (7, 0) (8, 0) (9, 0)},%
      {(0, 0) (1, 0) (2, 0) (3, 0) (6, 0) (7, 2) (8, 0) (9, 0)},%
      {(0,0)},%
      {(0, 0) (9, 0)}%
    }{
      \draw[yshift=-2*\i cm,sheet] plot coordinates {\pts};
    }
    % ---- singular points and labels ----
    \path
      (2,-5) [point] (3,-5) node{$b=1$}
      (7,-3) [point] (8,-3) node{$b=1$}
      (7,-8) [point] (8,-7.5) node{$b=2$}
    ;
    % ---- vertical lines ----
    \draw[dashed]
      (2,0) -- +(0,-14) [point]
      (7,0) -- +(0,-14) [point]
    ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

*Edit notes:*

- *spaces can now be handled, but are ignored by default*
- *alternative syntax for `\myparserdef` added*

---

Inspired by [Kpym's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/481179/117050) but thinking that the possibilities of `pgfparser` are insufficient, I wrote my own parser, that should be similar to pgf's, but allows the parsed elements to grab arguments. The following arguments are supported:

- `m` a mandatory argument
- `r{<delim>}` a mandatory argument delimited by `<delim>`
- `o` an optional argument in brackets (you can test for it with `\myIfNoValueTF`)
- `O{<default>}` an optional argument defaulting to `<default>`
- `d<delim1><delim2>` an optional argument delimited by `<delim1>` and `<delim2>` (you can test for it with `\myIfNoValueTF`)
- `D<delim1><delim2>{<default>}` an optional argument delimited by `<delim1>` and `<delim2>` defaulting to `<default>`
- `t<token>` an optional token (you can test for it with `\myIfBooleanTF`)

Despite the fact that the argument names are inspired by `xparse`, none of them care for balanced delimiters (e.g., `[[ab]]` would not be grabbed as `[ab]`, but as `[ab` with an orphaned `]`, so you'd have to use `[{[ab]}]`, this is like the LaTeX2e behaviour). Also all arguments are long by nature unlike `xparse` where you'd need to specify that using `+`.

You can define a parser using `\myparserdef{<name>}{<state>}{<meaning>}[<args>]{<code>}`, with `<name>` the name of the parser, `<state>` the state, `<meaning>` the meaning of a token, `<args>` an argument string (built from the arguments listed above, up to 9 arguments are supported) and `<code>` the code which should be executed for that combination of `<name>`, `<state>` and `<meaning>`. You can switch states using `\myparserstate{<state>}`, if you switch to `final` parsing is ended, the initial state is `initial`. All in all this is pretty similar to `pgfparser`s way of doing things. The biggest difference is, that my parser ignores blanks by default, however you can define an action for blanks with `\myparserdef{<name>}{<state>}{blank space}[<args>]{<code>}`. Many consecutive blanks are considered as one.

You can also use a different syntax for `\myparserdef` namely: `\myparserdef{<name>}{<state>}<token>[<args>]{<code>}` with `<token>` being a single token not surrounded by `{}` (spaces are ignored here, it is not checked whether `<token>` is really a single token, so be careful). In that case the same will be done as if you'd typed the `\meaning` of the `<token>`, so `\myparserdef{foo}{bar}a{baz}` does the same as `\myparserdef{foo}{bar}{the letter a}{baz}`.

A parser is executed using `\myparserrun{<name>}`. A parser needs at least one rule, else an error is thrown.

This parser system allows me to place coordinates inside of `\sheet`, which was the main reason why I found `pgfparser` insufficient.

I did all of this without using any packages, only LaTeX-Kernel macros, just for procrastinating reasons. Using for example `xparse` would shorten the code considerably.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}

% my parser >>>
\makeatletter
% logic helpers >>>
\long\def\myfi@An#1\fi#2{\fi}
\long\def\myfi@Ay#1\fi#2{\fi#2}
\long\def\myfi@By\fi#1{\fi#1}
\long\def\myfi@BTb\fi#1#2#3{\fi#2}
% <<<
% mynewdef >>>
\@ifdefinable\myifundefTF%>>>
  {%
    \def\myifundefTF#1%
      {%
        \ifdefined#1%
          \myfi@Ay
        \else
          \myfi@BTb
        \fi
        {%
          \ifx#1\relax
            \myfi@BTb
          \fi
          \@secondoftwo
        }%
      }%
  }%<<<
\@ifdefinable\mynewdef%>>>
  {%
    \protected\def\mynewdef{\@ifnextchar[{\mynewdef@a}{\mynewdef@a[]}}%
  }%<<<
\@ifdefinable\mynewdef@a%>>>
  {%
    \long\def\mynewdef@a[#1]#2#3#{\mynewdef@b{#1}#2{#3}}%
  }%<<<
\@ifdefinable\mynewdef@b%>>>
  {%
    \protected\long\def\mynewdef@b#1#2#3#4%
      {%
        \myifundefTF#2%
          {%
            #1\def#2#3{#4}%
          }
          {%
            \PackageError{my}{Command \string#2\space already defined}{}%
          }
      }%
  }%<<<
\mynewdef\myifcsundefTF#1%>>>
  {%
    \ifcsname #1\endcsname
      \myfi@Ay
    \else
      \myfi@BTb
    \fi
    {%
      \expandafter\ifx\csname #1\endcsname\relax
        \myfi@BTb
      \fi
      \@secondoftwo
    }%
  }%<<<
% <<<
% opt arg parsing >>>
\mynewdef[\long]\my@ifmark#1%>>>
  {%
    \ifx\my@mark#1%
      \myfi@BTb
    \fi
    \@secondoftwo
  }%<<<
\mynewdef[\protected\long]\myoarg@oarg#1%>>>
  {%
    \@ifnextchar[{\myoarg@oarg@{#1}}{#1{\my@mark}}%
  }%<<<
\mynewdef[\long]\myoarg@oarg@#1[#2]%>>>
  {%
    #1{#2}%
  }%<<<
\mynewdef[\protected\long]\myoarg@Oarg#1#2%>>>
  {%
    \@ifnextchar[{\myoarg@oarg@{#2}}{#2{#1}}%
  }%<<<
\mynewdef[\protected\long]\myoarg@darg#1#2#3%>>>
  {%
    \long\def\myoarg@darg@##1#1##2#2{##1{##2}}%
    \@ifnextchar#1{\myoarg@darg@{#3}}{#3{\my@mark}}%
  }%<<<
\mynewdef[\protected\long]\myoarg@Darg#1#2#3#4%>>>
  {%
    \long\def\myoarg@darg@##1#1##2#2{##1{##2}}%
    \@ifnextchar#1{\myoarg@darg@{#4}}{#4{#3}}%
  }%<<<
% <<<
% macros for string comparison >>>
\begingroup\def\:{\endgroup\let\my@sptoken= }\:
\mynewdef\my@mark{\my@mark@if@you@see@this@report@it}
\mynewdef\my@stop{\my@stop@if@you@see@this@report@it}
\mynewdef\myparser@final{final}
\mynewdef\myparser@noarg{noarg}
\mynewdef\myparser@blankspace{blank space}
% <<<
\mynewdef[\protected]\myparserdef#1#2%>>>
  {%
    \def\myparserdef@twoargs{{#1}{#2}}%
    \myparserdef@a
  }%<<<
\mynewdef[\protected]\myparserdef@a%>>>
  {%
    \futurelet\myparserdef@arg\myparserdef@b
  }%<<<
\mynewdef\myparserdef@b%>>>
  {%
    \ifx\myparserdef@arg\my@sptoken
      \myfi@BTb
    \fi
    \@secondoftwo
    {\myparserdef@gobble@space}
    {\myparserdef@c}%
  }%<<<
\mynewdef[\protected]\myparserdef@gobble@space%>>>
  {%
    \afterassignment\myparserdef@a
    \let\myparserdef@arg= % space after = to get spaces, too
  }%<<<
\mynewdef[\protected]\myparserdef@c#1%>>>
  {%
    \ifx\myparserdef@arg\bgroup
      \myfi@BTb
    \fi
    \@secondoftwo
    {%
      \def\myparserdef@arg{#1}%
      \ifx\myparser@blankspace\myparserdef@arg
        \myfi@BTb
      \fi
      \@secondoftwo
      {\expandafter\myparserdef@d\myparserdef@twoargs{blank space \space}}
      {\expandafter\myparserdef@d\myparserdef@twoargs{#1}}%
    }
    {\expandafter\myparserdef@d\myparserdef@twoargs{\meaning\myparserdef@arg}}%
  }%<<<
\mynewdef[\long]\myparserdef@d#1#2#3%>>>
  {%
    \myoarg@oarg{\myparserdef@e{#1}{#2}{#3}}%
  }%<<<
\mynewdef[\protected\long]\myparserdef@e#1#2#3#4#5%>>>
  {%
    % if that is the first rule for the parser, define space to be a no-op
    \myifcsundefTF{\myparser@name{#1}}%
      {%
        \expandafter\def
          \csname \myparser@name{#1} all blank space \space\space type\endcsname
          {noarg}%
        \expandafter\def
          \csname \myparser@name{#1} all blank space \space\space code\endcsname
          {\myparser@getnexttoken}%
        % use a macro as a flag that there is at least one parser rule defined
        \expandafter\def\csname\myparser@name{#1}\endcsname{}%
      }
      {}%
    % check whether the optional argument was used
    \my@ifmark{#4}
      {%
        % use a macro as flag that there is a rule for the specified state
        \expandafter\def\csname \myparser@name{#1} #2 #3 type\endcsname{noarg}%
        \def\myparserdef@arg@count{0}%
      }
      {%
        \edef\myparserdef@arg@count
          {\the\numexpr\myparserdef@argcount#4\my@mark}%
        \ifnum\myparserdef@arg@count>9%
          \PackageError{my}{Too many arguments for parser rule}
            {A maximum of 9 parameters is supported.}%
        \else
          \ifnum\myparserdef@arg@count=0%
            \expandafter\def\csname \myparser@name{#1} #2 #3 type\endcsname
              {noarg}%
          \else
            \expandafter\def\csname \myparser@name{#1} #2 #3 type\endcsname{#4}%
          \fi
        \fi
      }%
    % define what the code does
    \expandafter\def\csname \myparser@name{#1} #2 #3 code\endcsname{}%
    \expandafter\renewcommand\csname \myparser@name{#1} #2 #3 code\endcsname
      [\myparserdef@arg@count]{#5\myparser@getnexttoken}%
  }%<<<
\mynewdef\myparserdef@argcount#1%>>>
  {%
    \ifx\my@mark#1%
      \myfi@An
    \else
      \myfi@By
    \fi
    {\csname myparserdef@argcount@#1\endcsname}%
  }%<<<
\mynewdef\myparserdef@argcount@m%>>>
  {%
    +1%
    \myparserdef@argcount
  }%<<<
\mynewdef\myparserdef@argcount@o%>>>
  {%
    +1%
    \myparserdef@argcount
  }%<<<
\mynewdef\myparserdef@argcount@O#1%>>>
  {%
    +1%
    \myparserdef@argcount
  }%<<<
\mynewdef\myparserdef@argcount@d#1#2%>>>
  {%
    +1%
    \myparserdef@argcount
  }%<<<
\mynewdef\myparserdef@argcount@D#1#2#3%>>>
  {%
    +1%
    \myparserdef@argcount
  }%<<<
\mynewdef\myparserdef@argcount@r#1%>>>
  {%
    +1%
    \myparserdef@argcount
  }%<<<
\mynewdef\myparserdef@argcount@t#1%>>>
  {%
    +1%
    \myparserdef@argcount
  }%<<<
\mynewdef\myparser@name#1%>>>
  {%
    myparser #1%
  }%<<<
\mynewdef\myparser@rule#1%>>>
  {%
    \myparser@current\space #1\space \meaning\myparser@token
  }%<<<
\mynewdef\myparser@type#1%>>>
  {%
    \myparser@rule{#1} type%
  }%<<<
\mynewdef\myparser@code#1%>>>
  {%
    \myparser@rule{#1} code%
  }%<<<
\mynewdef[\protected]\myparserrun#1%>>>
  {%
    \myifcsundefTF{\myparser@name{#1}}
      {\PackageError{my}{No parser named '#1' defined}{}}
      {%
        \edef\myparser@current{\myparser@name{#1}}%
        \def\myparser@usersname{#1}%
        \def\myparser@state{initial}%
        \myparser@getnexttoken
      }%
  }%<<<
\mynewdef[\protected]\myparser@getnexttoken%>>>
  {%
    \ifx\myparser@state\myparser@final
      \myfi@An
    \else
      \myfi@By
    \fi
    {%
      \afterassignment\myparser@getnexttoken@a
      \let\myparser@token= % space after = to get spaces, too
    }%
  }%<<<
\mynewdef[\protected]\myparser@getnexttoken@a%>>>
  {%
    \myifcsundefTF{\myparser@type{\myparser@state}}
      {%
        \myifcsundefTF{\myparser@type{all}}
          {%
            \PackageError{my}
              {%
                No rule for parser '\myparser@usersname' in state
                '\myparser@state' for '\meaning\myparser@token'.
                Ignoring token%
              }
              {}%
            \myparser@getnexttoken
          }
          {\myparser@handle{all}}%
      }
      {\myparser@handle{\myparser@state}}%
  }%<<<
\mynewdef[\protected]\myparser@handle#1%>>>
  {%
    \expandafter\ifx\csname\myparser@type{#1}\endcsname\myparser@noarg
      \myfi@BTb
    \fi
    \@secondoftwo
    {\csname\myparser@code{#1}\endcsname}
    {\myparser@handle@args{#1}}%
  }%<<<
\mynewdef[\protected]\myparserstate#1%>>>
  {%
    \def\myparser@state{#1}%
  }%<<<
\mynewdef[\protected]\myparser@handle@args#1%>>>
  {%
    \def\myparser@stateorall{#1}%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\myparser@handle@args@a
    \csname\myparser@type{#1}\endcsname\my@mark\my@stop
  }%<<<
\mynewdef\myparser@handle@args@a%>>>
  {%
    \myparser@handle@args@b{}%
  }%<<<
\mynewdef[\long]\myparser@handle@args@b#1#2#3\my@stop%>>>
  {%
    \my@ifmark{#2}
      {\csname\myparser@code{\myparser@stateorall}\endcsname#1}
      {%
        \myifcsundefTF{myparser@handle@args@#2}
          {\PackageError{my}{Unknown argument type '#2'}{}}
          {\csname myparser@handle@args@#2\endcsname{#1}{#3}}%
      }%
  }%<<<
\mynewdef[\long]\myparser@handle@args@c#1#2%>>>
  {%
    \my@ifmark{#2}
      {\csname\myparser@code{\myparser@stateorall}\endcsname#1}
      {\myparser@handle@args@b{#1}#2\my@stop}%
  }%<<<
\mynewdef[\long]\myparser@handle@args@m#1#2#3%>>>
  {%
    \myparser@handle@args@c{#1{#3}}{#2}%
  }%<<<
\mynewdef[\protected\long]\myparser@handle@args@o#1#2%>>>
  {%
    \myoarg@oarg{\myparser@handle@args@m{#1}{#2}}%
  }%<<<
\mynewdef[\long]\myparser@handle@args@O#1#2%>>>
  {%
    \myparser@handle@args@O@{#1}#2\my@stop
  }%<<<
\mynewdef[\protected\long]\myparser@handle@args@O@#1#2#3\my@stop%>>>
  {%
    \myoarg@Oarg{#2}{\myparser@handle@args@m{#1}{#3}}%
  }%<<<
\mynewdef[\long]\myparser@handle@args@d#1#2%>>>
  {%
    \myparser@handle@args@d@{#1}#2\my@stop
  }%<<<
\mynewdef[\protected\long]\myparser@handle@args@d@#1#2#3#4\my@stop%>>>
  {%
    \myoarg@darg{#2}{#3}{\myparser@handle@args@m{#1}{#4}}%
  }%<<<
\mynewdef[\long]\myparser@handle@args@D#1#2%>>>
  {%
    \myparser@handle@args@D@{#1}#2\my@stop
  }%<<<
\mynewdef[\protected\long]\myparser@handle@args@D@#1#2#3#4#5\my@stop%>>>
  {%
    \myoarg@Darg{#2}{#3}{#4}{\myparser@handle@args@m{#1}{#5}}%
  }%<<<
\mynewdef[\long]\myparser@handle@args@r#1#2%>>>
  {%
    \myparser@handle@args@r@a{#1}#2\my@stop
  }%<<<
\mynewdef[\protected\long]\myparser@handle@args@r@a#1#2#3\my@stop%>>>
  {%
    \def\myparser@handle@args@r@b##1#2{\myparser@handle@args@c{#1{##1}}{#3}}%
    \myparser@handle@args@r@b
  }%<<<
\mynewdef[\long]\myparser@handle@args@t#1#2%>>>
  {%
    \myparser@handle@args@t@a{#1}#2\my@stop
  }%<<<
\mynewdef[\protected\long]\myparser@handle@args@t@a#1#2#3\my@stop%>>>
  {%
    \@ifnextchar#2%
      {\@firstoftwo{\myparser@handle@args@c{#1{\my@mark}}{#3}}}
      {\myparser@handle@args@c{#1{\my@stop}}{#3}}%
  }%<<<
\let\myIfNoValueTF\my@ifmark
\let\myIfBooleanTF\my@ifmark
\makeatother
% <<<

% the sheet path parser >>>
\makeatletter
\def\insertpath#1{\edef\sheetpath@{\unexpanded\expandafter{\sheetpath@#1}}}
\def\sheetpathcurve#1#2#3#4%
  {%
    to[out=0,in=180] ++({.5*\sheetlength},{#1*\sheetheight})
    \myIfBooleanTF{#3}{}{node[scale=\sheetdotsize,inner sep=0pt]{.}}
    \myIfNoValueTF{#4}{}{coordinate({#4})}
    to[out=0,in=180] ++({.5*\sheetlength},{#2*\sheetheight})
  }
\def\outputpath{\draw\sheetpath@;}
\def\sheet{\def\sheetpath@{}\myparserrun{sheet path}}
\makeatother
\myparserdef{sheet path}{initial}{the character (}[r,r)]
  {\insertpath{({#1},{#2*\sheetheight})}\myparserstate{started}}
\myparserdef{sheet path}{initial}{the character =}
  {\insertpath{(0,0)--++(\sheetlength,0)}\myparserstate{started}}
\myparserdef{sheet path}{started}{the character (}[r)]
  {\insertpath{coordinate({#1})}}
\myparserdef{sheet path}{started}{the character =}
  {\insertpath{--++(\sheetlength,0)}}
\myparserdef{sheet path}{started}{the letter u}[txd()]
  {\insertpath{\sheetpathcurve{.5}{-.5}{#1}{#2}}}
\myparserdef{sheet path}{started}{the letter U}[txd()]
  {\insertpath{\sheetpathcurve{1}{-1}{#1}{#2}}}
\myparserdef{sheet path}{started}{the letter d}[txd()]
  {\insertpath{\sheetpathcurve{-.5}{.5}{#1}{#2}}}
\myparserdef{sheet path}{started}{the letter D}[txd()]
  {\insertpath{\sheetpathcurve{-1}{1}{#1}{#2}}}
% making '.' a no-op, that way we can use it to end the search for an optional
% argument for instance
\myparserdef{sheet path}{started} .{}
\myparserdef{sheet path}{started}{the letter x}[d()]
  {%
    \myIfNoValueTF{#1}
      {%
        \insertpath
          {--node[scale=\sheetdotsize,inner sep=0pt]{.}++(\sheetlength,0)}%
      }
      {%
        \insertpath
          {%
            --node[scale=\sheetdotsize,inner sep=0pt]{.}
              coordinate({#1})
              ++(\sheetlength,0)
          }%
      }%
  }
\myparserdef{sheet path}{all}{the character ;}{\myparserstate{final}\outputpath}
% <<<

% sheet height and sheet length >>>
\pgfset
  {
    ,sheet height/.store in=\sheetheight
    ,sheet height=1
    ,sheet length/.store in=\sheetlength
    ,sheet length=1
    ,sheet dot size/.store in=\sheetdotsize
    ,sheet dot size=4
  }
%<<<

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[thick, sheet height=0.75]
    \sheet          ===     ===d(sp1)=;
    \sheet (0,-1)   ==d(sp2)===ux    =;
    \sheet (0,-2)   ==ux    ===Dx    =;
    \sheet (0,-3)   ===     ====     =;
    \sheet (0,-4)   ===     ===U(sp3)=;
    \sheet (0,-5.5) ==x(b1) ===x(b2) =;
  \end{scope}
  \draw[dashed]
    (b2) -- (sp1)
    (b1) -- (sp2)
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow ! This is a huge work. I'm impressed (like always I'm by the texperts ;)).

Comment: @Kpym there are many parts of the code that are not really necessary, so I could've shortened it (especially by using some LaTeX3 packages like `xparse`). But thanks.

Answer (score 5):

This is a *proof of concept* how to use `turtle` library to define the following "moves" :

- `up` make an up bump
- `up*` make an up bump with (red) dot
- `dn` make a down bump
- `dn*` make a down bump with (red) dot
- `*` put a (red) dot

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{turtle}
\tikzset{
  turtle/.cd,
  how/.style={out=0,in=180},
  home/.append style=right,
  */.style={/tikz/insert path={node[red,scale=4]{.}}},
  forward/.default=1.4142135,
  up/.style={left=45,forward,right,forward,left=45},
  up*/.style={left=45,forward,*,right,forward,left=45},
  dn/.style={right=45,forward,left,forward,right=45},
  dn*/.style={right=45,forward,*,left,forward,right=45},
  next/.style={/tikz/yshift=-1cm}
}

\begin{document}
  \tikz
    \draw[thick]
      [turtle={home,fd,fd,fd,fd,fd,fd,dn,fd},next,next]
      [turtle={home,fd,fd,dn,fd,fd,up*,fd},next,next]
      [turtle={home,fd,fd,up*,fd,fd,dn,fd},next]
      [turtle={home,fd,fd,fd,fd,fd,fd,fd,fd,fd},next]
      [turtle={home,fd,fd,fd,fd,fd,fd,up*,fd}]
    ;
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is a *proof of concept* how to use `pics` to define a singularity and then connect it to other ones.

The `singularity` pic can be used like this :

[image]

And a fool code example is here :

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{turtle}
\tikzset{
  fibers/.store in=\fibers,
  fiber/.pic={
    \path[pic actions] foreach \i in {0,...,\fibers} {(0,\i) coordinate (-\i) (0,0) -- (0,\fibers)};
  },
  singularity/.pic={
    \draw[#1,yscale=.5]
      foreach \i in \singularityinputs {(-1,\i) coordinate (-in\i) (-1,\i) edge[out=0,in=180] (0,0)}
      foreach \o in \singularityoutputs {(1,\o) coordinate (-out\o) (0,0) edge[out=0,in=180] (1,\o)}
      (0,0) node[fill,circle,inner sep=0,minimum width=1mm]{}
    ;
  },
  input/.store in=\singularityinputs,
  output/.store in=\singularityoutputs,
  sheets/.style = {input={#1},output={#1}}
}

\begin{document}
  \tikz
    \draw[thick,fibers=5]
      % define the fibers
      (0,0) pic(start){fiber}
      -- (2,0) pic[draw,dashed](a){fiber} pic[fill=red,sheets={}]{singularity}
      -- (5,0) pic[draw,dashed](b){fiber} pic[fill=red,sheets={}]{singularity}
      -- (7,0) pic(end){fiber}
      % put the singularities
      (a-3) pic[fill=red,sheets={-1,1}](A){singularity}
      (b-2) pic[fill=red,sheets={-1,0,1}](B){singularity}
      (b-4) pic[fill=red,sheets={-1,1}](C){singularity}
      % draw the sheets (by connecting singularities)
      (A-in-1) -- (A-in-1-|start-0) (A-in1) -- (A-in1-|start-0)
      (A-out1) -- (C-in-1) (A-out-1) -- (B-in1)
      (B-in0) -- (B-in0-|start-0) (B-in-1) -- (B-in-1-|start-0)
      (B-out-1) -- (B-out-1-|end-0) (B-out0) -- (B-out0-|end-0) (B-out1) -- (B-out1-|end-0)
      (C-in1) -- (C-in1-|start-0)
      (C-out1) -- (C-out1-|end-0) (C-out-1) -- (C-out-1-|end-0)
    ;
\end{document}
```

[image]